# How to access another widget on the page in appmaker from an event

Tags: widget, google-app-maker

I'd like to access another widget on the page, is there a direct way to do this?
I now about widget.parent.children... and so on, but on big pages, it is a pain, and it does not work if the structure changes...
Is there a way to get a widget by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access any element on the page using bellow command

```
widget.root.descendants.Button1
```

where Button1 is the element in seperate widget on the same page. You can write code to an element in a separate page using bellow code

```
app.pages.PageName1.descendants.ElementName1
```

Where PageName1 is the other page, and ElementName1 is the element in PageName1.
Hope this helps you in any way